# undefined method `name_cont' for Ransack::Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to use the ransank gem. But for some reason I get

> undefined method `name_cont' for Ransack::Search>:Ransack::Search

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index

    @q = User.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result
    @users = User.order(:id).includes(:employers)
    @users = User.order('last_name  ASC').page(params[:page]).per_page(2)
    #Adding CSV export
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

My index.html.erb

> ```
> <%= f.label :name_cont %>
> <%= f.search_field :name_cont %>
>
> <%= f.submit %> <% end %>
> ```

Comment: Is the `name_cont` method supposed to be a member of the `User` class then?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, you may need to [whitelist the `name` attribute for search](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/other-notes/#authorization-allowlistingdenylisting).

You can do this by setting your model's `self.ransackable_attributes` method, like so:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
 def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ["id", "name"] # <-- add this
  end
end
```

Comment: this was the piece of the puzzle I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ransack's helper to create the form too. My best guess is that you used `form_for` instead of `search_form_for` and thus getting the undefined error.

Another possibility is that your `User` model does not have an attribute `name`.
Try adding `name` to your model so that ransack knows what to search for.

Comment: are you getting the same error though after using `search_form_for`?

Comment: I am also having a similar issue . undefied method for 'title_cont'.